# Adding blur to an NSImage using Swift

Tags: swift, nsimage, nsimageview

I'm searching for a way to add a blur effect to a NSImage using Swift.

developing for iOS, UIImage provides a method like

```
applyLightEffectAtFrame:frame
```

... but i could not find something equal for Cocoa/an OSX-App.

**edit 1**: i tried to use CIFilter:

```
let beginImage = CIImage(data: responseData)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
filter.setValue(beginImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
filter.setValue(0.5, forKey: kCIInputIntensityKey)
// HOW CAN I MAKE AN NSIMAGE OUT OF THE CIIMAGE?
let newImage = ???
imageView.image = newImage
```

Comment: Core Image filters are the general equivalent to a lot of the image effects you can find on iOS.

Comment: edited my question above; i tried to use the CIFilter thinking i'm on a good way, but couldn't find out how i can convert the CIImage back to NSImage?

Comment: It's a simple enough process using image reps.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386650/converting-ciimage-into-nsimage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by just adding a content filter to my NSImageView within the Interface-Builder.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I don't see a "content filter" option in IB.

Comment: Ok found it – last tab in the inspector menu "fx"

Answer (score 2):

The following (taken from [here](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2009/Jun/msg00865.html)) works for me

```
    var originalImage = NSImage(named: "myImageName")
    var inputImage = CIImage(data: originalImage?.TIFFRepresentation)
    var filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
    filter.setDefaults()
    filter.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    var outputImage = filter.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as CIImage
    var outputImageRect = NSRectFromCGRect(outputImage.extent())
    var blurredImage = NSImage(size: outputImageRect.size)
    blurredImage.lockFocus()
    outputImage.drawAtPoint(NSZeroPoint, fromRect: outputImageRect, operation: .CompositeCopy, fraction: 1.0)
    blurredImage.unlockFocus()

    imageView.image = blurredImage
```

Hope it helps the new comers